# Vidalia and Tor: Controlling when the identity changes

Tags: tor

I'm performing some latency measurements over the Tor network. TO avoid congesting the relays, each run of my test lasts about 15 to 20 minutes, consuming an average bandwidth of 2 kbps.

Because of the way the relay works, my measurements get disrupted because the identity automatically changes every few minutes. I wonder if someone knows how to do these:

1. Specify the time interval between identity changes. Alternatively, disabling the automatic identity change and allowing me to use vidalia's control panel to change identities manually
2. Specify an IP address as an exit relay. I edited torrc, setting ExitNodes to an ipaddress, and StrictNode to 1, but after an initial connection to that specific exit relay and 1 http connection to the outside world, no subsequent traffic is routed out of tor.

I unfortunately can't seem to find an answer to my dilemma looking at previous questions. :-/  My setup consists of ubuntu 12.04 lts, installing vidalia and tor using apt-get and firefox connecting to tor using socks via localhost:9050

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Specify the time interval between identity changes.

Hi Nina, thanks for being careful about the load you put on the network! By default Tor cycles your circuits every ten minutes. You can customize this with the `MaxCircuitDirtiness` option in your torrc.

> 2) Specify an IP address as an exit relay.

Tor does not make this particularly easy. Probably the best option would be to extend one of your existing circuits to the desired endpoint. You can do this via stem using the [extend_circuit() method](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.extend_circuit).